# Bootstrap ul breaking float and displaying it under the left nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-lists

I am new to Bootstrap and I can't figure out why this is not working.  Here is the html so you can see for yourself.  The form is displaying under the left nav instead of to the right of the left nav.

This is the ul that I think is causing the problem

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#nav1">Nav1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#nav2">Nav2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#nav3">Nav3</a></li> 
  </ul>
```

Thanks in advance

Ralph

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Title Here</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->

        <!-- Custom StyleSheet -->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!-- Jquery css for search as you type -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- 
        ************************
        *** Fixed Top NavBar ***
        ************************
        -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #1C2D8E">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="#">Logo Here</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="../navbar/">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Support</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="./">Help<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>

            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </nav>
        <br /><br /><p>
        <!-- 
        *******************
        *** Left navbar ***
        *******************
        -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar" style="background-color: #A4A4A4;">
            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
                <br />
                <input id="sites" name="site" type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Select a Site...">
                <button name="submit">Select</button>
            </form>
            <hr> 
              <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active" id="#bg-dark-gray"><a id="font-yellow" href="#">Menu Item<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a id="font-yellow" href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
                <li><a id="font-yellow" href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
                <li><a id="font-yellow" href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
                <li><a id="font-yellow" href="">Menu Item</a></li>
                <li><a id="font-yellow" href="">Menu Item</a></li>
                <li><a id="font-yellow" href="">Menu Item</a></li>
                <li><a id="font-yellow" href="">Menu Item</a></li>
                <li><a id="font-yellow" href="">Menu Item</a></li>
                <li><a id="font-yellow" href="">Menu Item</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- 
            *****************************
            *** Start Content Section ***
            *****************************
            --> 
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: #ddd">
                <div class="panel-body">
                                        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal"><!-- START THE FORM -->
                        <!-- ************************* -->
                        <!--  F I R S T   C O L U M N  -->
                        <!-- ************************* -->

  <div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#nav1">Nav1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#nav2">Nav2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#nav3">Nav3</a></li> 
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="nav1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputCompany" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Company</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstname" value="" placeholder="Company Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputLastname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Address1</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastname" value="" placeholder="Address">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputFirstname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Address2</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstname" value="" placeholder="Address">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputLastname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">City</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastname" value="" placeholder="City">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputFirstname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">State</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstname" value="" placeholder="State">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputLastname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Zip Code</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastname" value="" placeholder="Zip Code">
                                </div>
                            </div>                          
                        </div>

                        <!-- ************************* -->
                        <!-- S E C O N D   C O L U M N -->
                        <!-- ************************* -->
                        <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Phone</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" value="" placeholder="phone">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Fax</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" value="" placeholder="Fax">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" value="" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Website</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" value="" placeholder="Website">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
                        </form> <!-- END THE FORM -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- END PANEL -->
          </div>    
        </div>  
        <div id="footer">
          <div class="container">
            <p class="muted credit">Copyright 2015 - Company Name <a href="#"></a></p>
          </div>
        </div>  
        <!-- JQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's javascript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/jax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (bellow) or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
        <!-- <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->

        <!-- Jquery css for search as you type -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(function() {
            var availableSites = [
              "PRC of South Florida","Arte In Pietra","Blessed Pediatric Care"          ];
            $( "#sites" ).autocomplete({
              source: availableSites
            });
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed expressing grid size for `panel` at the beginning of "start content section". If you would like the left sidebar and panel sits next to each other in Smartphone view as well, you should add `col-xs-...` to both divs as well. Check out a working example [****HERE****](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/pgodQy?editors=100)

```
<!-- 
    *******************
    *** Left navbar ***
    *******************
    -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar" style="background-color: #A4A4A4;">
```

and the second part:

```
<!-- 
        *****************************
        *** Start Content Section ***
        *****************************
        --> 
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-10 panel panel-default" style="background-color: #ddd">
```

Comment: Thank you zero point it worked great.  I have been working on this for day.